# Node.js communication with multiple nodes

Tags: node.js, ipc

I have 7 nodejs instances running on 1 host and currently they communicate with each other via [IPC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) and it works fine. Only now there runs a separate server for each nodejs instance.
This is because I cannot communicate from client to client directly only client to master.

Is there a library within nodejs to set up 1 server with multiple clients and with which you can communicate directly from one client to another?

Or should I set up 1 master and let the master handle the communication from the clients?